# What's the difference between a logic, an internal logic (language) of a category, an internal logic of a topos and a type theory?

Tags: logic, category-theory, formal-languages, topos-theory, categorical-logic

maybe this question doesn't make sense at all. I don't know exactly the meaning of all these concepts, except the internal language of a topos (and searching on the literature is not helping at all).

However, vaguely speaking by a logic I mean a pair $(\Sigma, \vdash)$ where $\Sigma$ is a signature (it has the types, functionals and relational symbols) and a consequence operator $\vdash$.

By an internal logic in a category I mean viewing each object as a type and each morphism as a term.

So what's the difference between a logic, an internal logic (language) of a category, an internal logic (language) of a topos and a type theory? Furthermore why the interchanging in the literature between the word "logic" and "language" when dealing with the internal properties of a category? Moreover, how higher order logic, modal logic and fuzzy logic suit in these concepts stated above?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 13):

The internal logic of a topos is an instance of the internal logic of a category (since toposes are special kinds of categories). The internal logic of toposes (instead of an arbitrary category) can also be interpreted with the Kripke-Joyal semantics. (**Update almost ten years later:** A form of the Kripke-Joyal semantics exists also for general categories which are not toposes.) For more on this, check part D of Johnstone's *Elephant* and chapter VI of Mac Lane's and Moerdijk's *Sheaves in Geometry and Logic*, [lecture notes by Thomas Streicher](http://www.mathematik.tu-darmstadt.de/%7Estreicher/CTCL.pdf), and of course the nLab articles on these matters.

I don't know the term "internal logic of a type theory". But check the (very accessible) introduction of the [HoTT book](http://homotopytypetheory.org/book/) on how type theory and logic are related.

The terms "internal logic" and "internal language" are often used synonymously. Personally, I prefer "internal language", since this stresses that one can use it not only to *reason* internally, but also to *construct objects and morphisms* internally.

The internal language of a topos $\mathcal{E}$ is higher-order in the sense that, because of the existence of a subobject classifier, every object $X \in \mathcal{E}$ has an associated [power object](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/power+object) $\mathcal{P}(X) \in \mathcal{E}$ which one can quantify over in the internal language. (In the special case $\mathcal{E} = \mathrm{Set}$, the internal language is really the same as the usual mathematical language and $\mathcal{P}(X)$ is simply the power set of $X$.) In an arbitrary category, power objects need not exist, such that their internal language is (at best) first-order. Generally, richer categorical properties allow you to interpret greater fragments of first-order logic, this is neatly explained in Johnstone's part D.

Any [Lawvere-Tierney topology](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Lawvere-Tierney+topology) in a topos gives rise to a modal operator in its associated internal language. (These operators can have concrete geometric meanings, for instance "on a dense open set it holds that" or "on an open neighbourhood of a point $x$ it holds that".)

I don't know of a direct relationship between fuzzy logic and the internal language of toposes, see [an older question here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/55957/fuzzy-logic-and-topos-theory).

Comment: On little clarification, because this might give the impression that, as soon as you have a subobject classifier, you get power objects.  You also need exponentials (i.e., Cartesian closure).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But HoTT book deals only with a specific kind of type theory where types correspond to homotopy type of topological spaces. Furthermore, I still confused by the fact that there is no standard definition of a logic and dealing with signatures is not exact "logic", it's just a "interpretation" in a linguistic sense of a "logic". Moreover in a topos or a category it's not clear exact where is the signature of a logic (in the sense I have cited in my question). It's not clear too why there are more logics than categories.

Comment: @user40276: I'm not quite sure whether I understand you correctly. Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a category. Then the signature induced by $\mathcal{C}$ has all objects of $\mathcal{C}$ as sorts (this is terminology from the *Elephant*, in your question you said *type*), all morphisms as function symbols and all subobjects as relations. Andreas: You are quite right, of course.

Comment: Ok, so, for instance, a predicate symbol would be a subobject (in the case of first order logic)? Furthermore, I still confused by the fact that some references says that an internal language defines a theory and not a logic?

Comment: Yes, you are right that a predicate symbol would be a subobject.

Comment: @user40276:  yes, think of an arbitrary relation as the subset (subobject) of the "full" relation.  An $n$-ary relation is a set in the Cartesian product of its $n$ domains.

Answer (score 11):

Your definition of logic is pretty much correct. A logic contains both the *language* which the signature $\Sigma$ generates and the deductive system defined by $\vdash$.

A *type theory* is a logic with different sorts of individuals (called "types") and constructions that generate new types from existing ones, like product and arrow types.

An *internal logic* is a type theory derived from a category and the *internal language* is the language part of that logic. Specifically, the atomic sorts of the internal language are the objects of the category. Since a topos is a specific category of categories, the internal logic of a topos is the derived type theory.

The modalities of modal logic can sometimes be related to operators on subobjects in a category, but only if they preserve logical equivalence: $\alpha\iff\beta$ should imply $\Box\alpha \iff \Box \beta$. Otherwise, the induced function of subobjects is not well-defined.

Fuzzy logic is misnamed. It is more like a model theory than a logic.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. In an arbitrary category there is no power object nor subobject classifies, so I don't know how can you create $\forall$ and $\exists$ as adjoint functors.

Comment: Nobody said the internal logic of an arbitrary category was any good. That's why we like topoi, or at least Cartesian closed categories, so much.

Comment: Every part of the logic requires some structure on the category for a sound interpretation. Not much is needed for a poset of subobjects, however. If a category has pullbacks, then each morphism induces an inverse image map between these posets. If a category has Cartesian products then quantifiers are adjoints to the inverse image maps of these products.

Comment: So not every logic can be encoded as a category? If the answer is yes, it's kind of weird because I can always pick the free topos generated by some signature.

Comment: @user40276: it is the other way around. Not every category has the structure that is required to soundly interpret higher order constructive logic. You can turn a (small) category into a signature and then turn that signature into a topos, but that topos is rarely equivalent to the original category.

Comment: Ok, so not every category is a logic, but the reverse statement is true?

Comment: @user40276: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j4XT-l-_3y0. I would say that is a category of theories in higher order constructive logic L and a category of categories C and some bifunctor $L\to C$ that reflects equivalences of categories.

Comment: I can't seem to find a source that talks about the internal logic of a category (as a type theory), and not just the internal language. Anyone have recommendations?